# Should an answer be downvoted even when long time has passed or should we let it be "water under the bridge"

Tags: discussion

I've seen the reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25444829/1675891) and, obviously, it just hooked on the pre-existing replies without adding any value. I was going to just ignore it but the comment made me believe that it was an intentional rep-chasing case.

Since our site is based on the rep corresponding to the quality, I feel that I should downvote. On the other hand, it's been so long time so maybe I shouldn't. I'm not invested enough to check out the other posts of the regarded user, so I can't say anything about a pattern.

I wonder what should be done in this particular case.

Comment: Don't worry about time. Don't worry about patterns. Is the answer bad? Would you downvote it if it was posted today? Then downvote away.

Comment: Is it factually incorrect? I would reserve downvotes for answers that are badly formatted or incorrect, but rewording other people's posts? Not sure I would downvote for that, sometimes you need another point of view to understand the solution.

Comment: @Draken Excellent point. Perhaps I was wrong to downvote. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Draken There's rewording and rewording. I've seen answers that re-explain a solution already given but the explanation is substantially different and worth preserving. I've also seen people "reword" an earlier answer in such a way that adds nothing useful, even though I'm sure the author thinks their point of view is oh so worthwhile.

Comment: @Louis Correct, that I can understand. However, who's to say what some people would find useful and others not? Sometimes a reiteration in an alternative way can make some people's light bulbs shine. Unless it's a very similar copy and paste or really isn't adding anything significant, I would still leave it as is.

Comment: @Louis In this particular case, it seems likely that the user just saw a good answer and wanted to get "in on the action". I can't know for sure, of course. That's why I'm asking here, to get a more balanced view.

Comment: @Draken I see how the comments are getting more general (which is good, of course) and I feel that I should remind that the question was primarily meant for this particular case.

Comment: @AndyJ The author's intent is not easily figured out. Things may look one way but be actually different. For instance, I probably posted some seemingly good but ultimately wrong answers that looked like I was posting quickly without regards to accuracy to win FGITW when in fact I really, but mistakenly, thought I had the answer. When I see answers that are repeating earlier ones, I decide whether I think it adds *something* and vote accordingly. Sometimes I comment saying the answer is already covered by an earlier one, or ask what it adds that was not already said.

Comment: You vote for answers - ***not*** to award or remove rep from the author. That's why tooltips for the voting buttons say "This answer is useful" and "This answer is not useful" instead of "The author of this post deserves more reputation" and "The author of this post deserves less reputation".